# ¿Como puedo convertir decímal una celda en Excel que tiene texto 0h0m0s?

Tags: excel

Tengo varios archivos de Raw Data en los cuales en una celda muestra el tiempo total de un evento, la celda está de esta forma 5h27m16s. Necesito convertir eso a 5 horas, 27 minutos y 16 segundos a decimales en una fórmula.

Intente usar `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `LEN` y `MID` pero ya que las celdas varían en cuanto a longitud e información, por ejemplo 2h34s o 34m54s, no he podido.

También intenté separar vía "texto a columna" pero lo tendría que separar por las letras y ya que existen celdas sin la letra h la separación no funciona. Lo que hice fue crear una fórmula para sustitutir las letras por dos puntos ":", use la fórmula `Substitute(Substitute(Substitute(J3," h", ":"), "m", ":",), "s", ":")` funcionó en su mayoría, todas las celdas con información como 0h0m0s lo convertió a tiempo para posteriormente multiplicarlo por 24 y dar con el decimal. Pero en celdas en las cuales no hay horas o h como 39m10s, la fórmula regresa 38:10 y al multiplicacarlo por 24 regresa 34.16.

Comment: ¿Y querés por fórmula? ¿No preferís `[separar texto en columnas]`?

Comment: Si los casos de entrada son complicados, tu fórmula será complicada (por ejemplo, buscando si aparecen o no las cadenas 'h' o 'm' y parseando el texto de forma acorde). Como no muestras un problema concreto (incluyendo tu código), parece que simplemente pides que alguien te proporcione la solución. Por favor, revisa [help].

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta y perdón por la falta de información, es la primera vez que posteo aquí l,

Comment: Disculpa, cuando dices "a decimales", te refieres a que tu unidad es el dia? (24 horas) o sea 1 = 24h00m00s?, otro detalle, como son las pocibles entradas? existe 24h00m00s o solo es 24h?, existe 39m04s o solo es 39m4s? existe 5h00m14s o solo es 5h14s?

Answer (score 1):

En este caso necesitamos que Excel reconozca cada elemento y diferencie si es una hora, minuto o segundo:

Hora: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-1,1)),"00")`

Minutos: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1,1)),"00")`

Segundos: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("s",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1,1)),"00")`

Luego usamos cada uno dentro de la formula `=TIME(Hour,Min,Seg)`

Ahora cambiamos el formato a general para obtener el equivalente en decimales usando la función `=TEXT(value,format_text)`

Nos quedaría la siguiente formula:

```
=TEXT(TIME(IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)-1,1)),"00"),IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1,1)),"00"),IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("s",A1)-2,2),MID(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1,1)),"00")),"General")
```

[image]